# JS/CSS files not refreshing (probably server side)

Tags: apache, typo3, virtualbox, centos7

I'm working on a javascript file. Everything was functioning normally for my first few edits, but now when I make changes and reload my page, I get a browser console error `SyntaxError: illegal character`, and when I check the source, I see an old version of my file with a bunch of �s at the end.

I've been working on this site without issue for a week or two. However, the other day I had a similar issue to this with a CSS file. I think I got it working by renaming the file, refreshing, and naming it back. It still doesn't refresh properly, and obviously this isn't a practical way to do development.

**My Environment**

- I'm developing a website on Centos 7 under VirtualBox in Windows 7.
- My site code is in a shared folder. (In Windows, accessible by Centos).
- Apache, PHP 7, MariaDB.
- TYPO3 8.7.3 CMS
- I view my site at a local domain defined in my Windows hosts file.

**What I've Tried**

- Refresh page (multiple times, using Ctrl+F5).
- View JS file directly. Refresh. (at mydomain/typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/js/file.js)
- Add `?somerandomstring` after file.js and refresh.
- Clear my CMS caches, using "Flush all caches".
- Rename my CMSs .htaccess file. In Centos run `/sbin/service httpd restart`. Refresh JS file.
- Open JS file in other browser.
- On restarting Centos, and refreshing, I get the current version of the file. But if I edit it again, then I get the same error.
- If I undo the changes to my file, then it loads and runs normally.

I think this rules out it being my browser. I think renaming .htaccess *should* rule out it being the CMS, but I don't have the knowledge to be certain of that.

So, what do I check next?

**Edit:**

Also noticed, If I edit my file to make it shorter, it trims the old file to the length of the new file.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my assets (css, js, images, etc.).
The only thing that works (as of my current knowledge) is adding a random number next to the url like this: `/main.js?someRandomNumber`.

This forces the browser to reload the file and load new code.

To achieve this, use php like this:

```
<script src=<?php echo '"main.js?' . rand() .'"'; ?>></script>
```

If you find a better way to do this please let me know...

Comment: This isn't my issue. I've tried reloading the file directly and adding `?randomwhatever` to the end of the url. I still get the file with the same errors.

Comment: Then try making a backup of your website and then delete the original website. After deleting, restart the server service and upload the website again.

Comment: If I restart the server OS, it loads the new version.But it has the same issue once I edit the files again.

Comment: I am not a server admin, so I don't know what is happening with your server. Have you tried re installing the whole server? That could help.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like an issue with your vbox setup. In general if you press ctrl+f5 your browser will reload all scripts.

Adding a random query string to a script is a very bad idea, since it is then a new resource every time you access it via http. This should be done with a checksum or modification time (depending on your deployment strategy)

The following example works, if you do not upload the script every time you deploy your project

```
<script src="path/to/script.js?v=<?= filemtime($file); ?>"><script>
```

An alternative would be

```
<script src="path/to/script.js?v=<?= md5_file($file); ?>"></script>
```

That way your browser should identify it as a new resource once the v value changes.

If you access the file via http directly (for example with curl) and it returns the wrong version of the file, you face problems independet from typo3. I also doubt it has to do with apache.

I guess you have to install the guestadditions in your virtualhost instance. Additionally i would make sure all permissions are set correctly.

For clarification: Where is the file you access located? If you access some generated/concatenated file from typo3 (for example typo3temp/compressor), it may be the problem, those files get saved there, but their source is somewhere else.